# Can not reset input value

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am trying to implement a TextInput that has a clear button. A minimalistic exmaple would look like this:

```
const SearchView = () => {
  const [input, setInput] = useState();
  const [searching, setSearching] = useState(false);

  const inputRef = useRef();

  return (
    <View style={{ width: '100%', flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <Input
            textInputConfig={{
              onFocus: () => {
                setSearching(true);
              },
              onChangeText: setInput,
              placeholderTextColor: colors.backgroundActive,
              placeholder: 'Search...',
              value: input,
              ref: inputRef,
            }}
          />
        </View>
        {searching ? (
          <Text
            style={[globalStyles.textBody, { marginLeft: 12 }]}
            onPress={() => {
              setInput('');
              inputRef.current.clear();
              inputRef.current.blur();
              setSearching(false);
            }}
          >
            Cancel
          </Text>
        ) : undefined}
      </View>
)
```

Input Component:

```
const Input = ({label, textInputConfig, labelStyle, inputStyle, invalid, alignment}) => (
    <>
      {label ? <Text style={[globalStyles.textBody,styles.label, labelStyle]}>{label}</Text> : undefined}
      <TextInput style={[globalStyles.textBody,styles.input, inputStyle, invalid ? {borderColor: 'darkred'} : undefined, alignment ? {textAlign: alignment} : {textAlign: 'left'}]} {...textInputConfig}/>
    </>
  );
```

I want the "Cancel" button to appear once the input is focussed which is working great. I also want to blur and clear the input field once the user clicks the "Cancel" button, which is not working. The input gets blurred, but the value remains. If you focus it again, and then click "Cancel" again it works as expected.

Comment: Where is this `Input` component coming from?

Comment: Oh sorry, I should have made that clearer in the first place. Input is a Styles wrapper for TextInput. TextInputConfig object is being spread inside there as props of TextInput.

Comment: Your implementation is correct, but you don't need the inputRef.current.clear(); Removing it should work.

Comment: @WillianGit thanks! However this is not the case. I really have no idea what’s going on here, because I also felt like this should work…

Comment: Can you show the `Input` component? Help us have a [minimal, reproducible, example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I have updated the post to include the Input component

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass ref as a prop, you need to wrap the component in `fowartRef()` HOC, because refs work in a different way than traditional props. It should look like this

```
const Input = forwardRef(() => ({label, textInputConfig, labelStyle, inputStyle, invalid, alignment}, ref) => (
<>
  {label ? <Text style={[globalStyles.textBody,styles.label, labelStyle]}>{label}</Text> : undefined}
  <TextInput style={[globalStyles.textBody,styles.input, inputStyle, invalid ? {borderColor: 'darkred'} : undefined, alignment ? {textAlign: alignment} : {textAlign: 'left'}]} {...textInputConfig}/>
</> ));
```

Comment: That is a good point! However the inputs state is managed in the parent component, so ref-forwarding should not be the issue here, right? setInput('') should still clear the text.

Comment: <Text> has no onPress property, it won't work, If you want to clear it with pressing text, wrap text with <TouchableOpacity> or <Pressable> component

Comment: <Text> has an onPress prop: https://reactnative.dev/docs/text#onpress